# Prove :$\ln(n+1)+\frac{1}{1+n}\geq \ln(n+2) $

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

> I have to prove the following for any natural number $n$,
>   $$\ln(n+1)+\frac{1}{n+1} \geq \ln(n+2).$$

What i tried so far
$$\ln(n+1) +(1/(1+n)) \geq  \ln(n+1) + \ln(1/(1+n)) +1$$
I found out if i can somehow put the +1 inside the $\ln(1/(1+n))$ I can solve my inequality. But I could not find any way.

Thank you!

Comment: $$\frac{1}{n+1} \geq \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \ln(n+2) - \ln(n+1) \ldots$$ No?

Comment: By MVT, $\log(n+2)-\log(n+1) = \frac{1}{n+x} < \frac{1}{n+1}$ for some $x \in (1,2)$.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$\log(n+2)-\log(n+1)=\int_{n+1}^{n+2}\frac{dx}{x}$$
and since $\frac{1}{x}$ is a decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$,
$$ \log(n+2)-\log(n+1) < \int_{n+1}^{n+2}\frac{dx}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1} $$
is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$\ln(n+2) = \ln\left((n+1) + 1\right) = \ln\left((n+1)(1 + \frac{1}{n+1})\right) = \ln(n+1) + \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right) \overset{(*)}{\leq}\\ \ln(n+1) + \frac{1}{n+1}$$
$(*)$ Knowing that $\ln(1+x)\leq x$

Comment: Can you give me a proof of $ln(1+x) ≤x$ ?

Comment: $\ln(1+x)=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{t+1}\le\int_0^x dt=x$

Answer (score 1):

Prove that $\forall X \in R_+^*$; $ln(1+X)<X$

And since $\forall n \in N$ $\frac{1}{n+1}>0$

Apply on it the the upper formula

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln(n+1)+\frac{1}{n+1} \geq \ln(n+2) \iff \ln \left(\frac{n+2}{n+1} \right)\leq \frac{1}{n+1} \iff \ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{n+1} \right)\leq \frac{1}{n+1}\iff \ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{n+1} \right)^{n+1}\leq \ln e =1 \quad \square $$

since $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$\left( 1+\frac{1}{n+1} \right)^{n+1}\leq e$$

Comment: Can you explain me why the last inequality holds?

Comment: I've upadated with explanation

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\ln(x+1) \le x$ taking  $x=\frac{1}{n+1}$ we get

$$\ln(n+2)-\ln(n+1)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{1+n}+1\right)\le\frac{1}{1+n}$$ 
$$\implies\ln(n+1)+\frac{1}{1+n}\geq \ln(n+2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function
$$f(x)=\log (x+1)+\frac{1}{x+1}-\log (x+2)$$ $$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2 (x+2)}$$ $$f''(x)=\frac{3 x+5}{(x+1)^3 (x+2)^2}$$ So, for $x>0$, $f(x)$ is decreasing with a positive second derivative. Since $f(0)=1-\log(2)>0$, then  $???$

Answer (score 0):

$ \exp$ is an increasing function, with $D= \mathbb{R}$, and with $R= (0,\infty)$:

$x_1 < x_2 \iff \exp(x_1) < \exp(x_2).$

LHS: Raise to the exponent:

$\exp(\ln(n+1) +1/(n+1)) =$

$ (1+n)\exp(1/(n+1))$ ;

RHS:

$\exp(\ln(n+2)) = n+2;$

Need to show LHS $\ge$ RHS for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$\iff:$

$\exp(1/(n+1)) \ge \dfrac{n+2}{n+1} = $

$1+ \dfrac{1}{n+1}$.

Expand:

$\exp(1/(n+1)) = 1 + 1/(n+1) +$

$ (1/2!)(1/(n+1))^2 +....\gt $

$1+1/(n+1).$